# Is there any way to show all screenshots I have posted on SO?

Tags: discussion

I've asked and answered a few questions that include a visualization of some sort using the `Image <img> Gtrl+G` functionality. Is there any way to list or display all these images that I've posted? I suspect the answer is "no", but I'm amazed by how many interesting "extra" features that exist for SO, like [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new) and [StackOverflow Trends](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/trends?tags=javascript%2Cpython). And I've only recently discovered those, so maybe something like this exists as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1240445?opt.textResults=true) to find, in a post body, the first occurrence an `<img>` tag that has its src attribute point to `https://i.stack.imgur.com/`. The query output (as text) can then be copied in an html file that you open in a browser.

Using both [PATINDEX](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and [CHARINDEX](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to do the right string manipulation.

It is left as an (challenging) exercise for the reader to find all the `<img>` tags in the body of a single post.

```sql
select concat( 
         '<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/q/'
       , id
       , '">'
       , title
       , '</a><br>'
       , left(img, convert(int, charindex('>', img, 36)) )
       , '<br>')
 --  , charindex('>',img, 36)
from
(
select substring(
         p.body, 
         convert(int, patindex(N'%<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/%', p.body)),
         len(p.body)) img
      , q.title
      , p.id
from posts p
inner join posts q on q.id = coalesce(p.parentid, p.id)
where p.owneruserid = 3437787
and p.body like '%<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/%" alt="%>%'
) data
```

Here are the first 6 to 8 results of that query:

```html
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/q/32906263">Knit pdf from rmd script by clicking an executable r file</a><br><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikhEz.png" alt=".Rexe"><br>                                                                                           
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/q/39335793">How do I get rid of this error message in Rstudio: Error creating notebook: object 'html_notebook' not found?</a><br><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xPE9.png" alt="enter image description here"><br>                
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/q/40264531">ggplot: How to increase space between axis labels for categorical data?</a><br><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/hw8Sf.png" alt="enter image description here"><br>                                                      
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/q/41823277">R script in Power BI returns date as Microsoft.OleDb.Date</a><br><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNZjk.png" alt="enter image description here"><br>                                                                    
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/q/41942451">R script in Power BI returns date as Microsoft.OleDb.Date</a><br><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3GXz.png" alt="enter image description here"><br>                                                                    
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/q/43492098">How to run a file in IPython console as default instead of terminal?</a><br><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCHDC.png" alt="enter image description here"><br>                                                         
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/q/44649725">moving average or rolling mean pandas without any window size</a><br><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHu6L.png" alt="enter image description here"><br>                                                                
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/q/43657731">Running code line by line versus as a selection (in Ipython using Spyder)</a><br><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tf4T.png" alt="enter image description here"><br>                                                    
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/q/44164094">Run code selection in Spyder without changing the active window to IPython console</a><br><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UUHE.png" alt="enter image description here"><br>                                           
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/q/44302726">Pandas: How to store cProfile output in a pandas DataFrame?</a><br><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwC3q.png" alt="enter image description here"><br>
```

---

[Knit pdf from rmd script by clicking an executable r file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32906263)
[image: .Rexe]
[How do I get rid of this error message in Rstudio: Error creating notebook: object 'html_notebook' not found?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39335793)
[image]
[ggplot: How to increase space between axis labels for categorical data?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40264531)
[image]
[R script in Power BI returns date as Microsoft.OleDb.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41823277)
[image]
[R script in Power BI returns date as Microsoft.OleDb.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41942451)
[image]
[How to run a file in IPython console as default instead of terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43492098)
[image]
[moving average or rolling mean pandas without any window size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44649725)
[image]
[Running code line by line versus as a selection (in Ipython using Spyder)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43657731)
[image]
[Run code selection in Spyder without changing the active window to IPython console](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44164094)
[image]
[Pandas: How to store cProfile output in a pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44302726)
[image]

Comment: Very cool, thanks! Is there any way to include question title in the output? By that I mean something like: `title, image, title, image` etc

Comment: @vestland now done

Comment: This is really great! I tend to remember which plots I've produced, but often forget how, when and where. So this is going to save me a lot of time when I'm looking at previous work. Thank you again!

Answer (score 7):

Yes, search for [`user:me url:"i.stack.imgur.com"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3Ame%20url%3A%22i.stack.imgur.com%22)

Comment: Thanks for answering! Do you happen to know if there's some way I can *display* all of them at the same time? Or make the screenshots appear under the search results from `user:3437787 url:"i.stack.imgur.com"`?

Comment: You can't, at least not without a userscript. Also note that this search assumes you never used any third party services to upload images